# Programmatically suspend/close the app

Tags: ios, ipad, titanium, appcelerator

How can I suspend/close my iPad app programmatically? I wanted to show the terms of use on app start up. If user presses the Accept button the app should continue. If user presses the Decline button the app should be suspended/closed.

PS : The app is built using Titanium Appcelerator framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try calling exit() but, to be honest, i doubt that the behaviour you want is desirable. i haven't seen any other apps do it - i'm not sure it'd be considered acceptable by Apple.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mike. Actually I was not given correct requirement. The client only wanted to show the disclaimer and Terms of use on very first load only! Then, I used App Properties to store the flag.. that's all! :)

Answer (score 1):

You never exit from an iPhone or iPad application.
If it does apple takes it as a crash and surely reject your application.

In your case, the best solution will be displaying another screen which display a message like: "You cannot access the application until you accept the terms" or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exit(0)`; whenever you want to exit the app. I have implemented this code in my project and it works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply..but I'm developing the app on *titanium appcelerator framework* which doesn't provide the exit(0) method! :(